# how to resolve web api error 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, sql-view

I am creating **ASP.Net MVC WebApi** to share my data to bank. In this regard i have created an **SQL View** bit when i am testing my WebApi it is giving an **'System.OutOfMemoryException'** error because i have more the 1 million record in SQL View.
My Code is given below:-
**This is my controller**

```
 public class InvoiceController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<VBank_invoice> Get()
        {
            using (kmcEntities entities = new kmcEntities())
            {
                return entities.VBank_invoice.ToList();
            }
        }

        public VBank_invoice Get(string consumer)
        {
            using (kmcEntities entities = new kmcEntities())
            {
                return entities.VBank_invoice.FirstOrDefault(e => e.consumer_no == consumer);
            }
        }
    }
```

**My SQL View Class**

```
public partial class VBank_invoice
    {
        public int sno { get; set; }
        public string consumer_no { get; set; }
        public string consumer_name { get; set; }
        public string consumer_address { get; set; }
        public string billing_month { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> current_Charges { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> outstanding_Arrears { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Arrears_15 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> part_payment_arrears { get; set; }
        public string billing_period_code { get; set; }
        public string consumer_checkdigit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> due_date { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is my Model.Context.cs File**

```
 public partial class kmcEntities : DbContext
    {
        public kmcEntities()
            : base("name=kmcEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<VBank_invoice> VBank_invoice { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be serialize object model using the select query.

```
public class InvoiceController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<VBank_invoice> Get()
    {
        using (kmcEntities entities = new kmcEntities())
        {
            return entities.VBank_invoice.select(m => new {
           m.sno, m.consumer_no,m.consumer_name,  m.consumer_address, 
           m.billing_month, m.current_Charges, m.outstanding_Arrears, 
           m.Arrears_15, m.part_payment_arrears, m.billing_period_code, 
           m.consumer_checkdigit, m.due_date }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```